# Creating an ID with spaces

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I know that you aren't supposed to create an ID with spaces and that

```
<div id="id one"></div>
```

will just create a div with id of `id`.
However a project I am doing using a json file which is set up with a bunch of data, part of the data is the name of the section the user is clicking on to retrieve more data through ajax. However the way it is set up the id for each part on the `descriptions.html` page needs to match the data in the json file.

I don't want to hyphenate it because having "Build-a-Site" display on my webpage looks just terrible.

We are not supposed to change the ajax or json set up but I'm willing to if there is no other way.

Here is the javascript file that is deciding what is placed on the page, I tried replacing `newContent += ('<a href="descriptions.html#');` with `newContent += ('<a href="descriptions.html#').replace(/-/g, "");` but that did not remove the hyphens on the page.

```
// NOTE: This example will not work locally in all browsers. 
// Please try it out on the website for the book http://javascriptbook.com/code/c08/
// or run it on your own server.

$(function() {                                    // When the DOM is ready

  var times;                                      // Declare global variable
  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {                   // Before requesting data
      if (xhr.overrideMimeType) {                 // If supported
        xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json"); // set MIME to prevent errors
      }
    }
  });

  // FUNCTION THAT COLLECTS DATA FROM THE JSON FILE
  function loadTimetable() {                    // Declare function
    $.getJSON('data/example.json')              // Try to collect JSON data
    .done( function(data){                      // If successful
      times = data;                             // Store it in a variable
    }).fail( function() {                       // If a problem: show message
      $('#event').html('Sorry! We could not load the timetable at the moment');
    });
  }

  loadTimetable();                              // Call the function


  // CLICK ON THE EVENT TO LOAD A TIMETABLE 
  $('#content').on('click', '#event a', function(e) {  // User clicks on event

    e.preventDefault();                                // Prevent loading page
    var loc = this.id.toUpperCase();                   // Get value of id attr

    var newContent = '';                               // Build up timetable by
    for (var i = 0; i < times[loc].length; i++) {      // looping through events
      newContent += '<li><span class="time">' + times[loc][i].time + '</span>';
      newContent += ('<a href="descriptions.html#');
      newContent += times[loc][i].title.replace(/ /g, '-') + '">';
      newContent += times[loc][i].title + '</a></li>';
    }

    $('#sessions').html('<ul>' + newContent + '</ul>'); // Display times on page

    $('#event a.current').removeClass('current');       // Update selected item
    $(this).addClass('current');

    $('#details').text('');                             // Clear third column
  });

  // CLICK ON A SESSION TO LOAD THE DESCRIPTION
  $('#content').on('click', '#sessions li a', function(e) { // Click on session
    e.preventDefault();                                     // Prevent loading
    var fragment = this.href;                               // Title is in href

    fragment = fragment.replace('#', ' #');                 // Add space after#
    $('#details').load(fragment);                           // To load info

    $('#sessions a.current').removeClass('current');        // Update selected
    $(this).addClass('current');
  });


  // CLICK ON PRIMARY NAVIGATION
  $('nav a').on('click', function(e) {                       // Click on nav
    e.preventDefault();                                      // Prevent loading
    var url = this.href;                                     // Get URL to load

    $('nav a.current').removeClass('current');               // Update nav
    $(this).addClass('current');

    $('#container').remove();                                // Remove old part
    $('#content').load(url + ' #container').hide().fadeIn('slow'); // Add new
  });

});
```

JSON

```
{
    "L1": [
        {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "HTML"
        },
        {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "CSS"
        },
        {
            "time": "$2.99",
            "title": "Build a Site"
        },
        {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "Javascript"
        },
        {
            "time": "$3.99",
            "title": "Interactive Website"
        },
        {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "PHP"
        },
        {
            "time": "$4.99",
            "title": "Node.js"
        }
    ],
    "L2": [
       {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "Python"
        },
        {
            "time": "$2.99",
            "title": "Java"
        },
        {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "Ruby"
        },
        {
            "time": "$1.99",
            "title": "Ruby on Rails"
        },
        {
            "time": "$2.99",
            "title": "C++"
        },
        {
            "time": "$2.99",
            "title": "C#"
        },
        {
            "time": "$4.99",
            "title": "R"
        }
    ],
    "L3": [
       {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "SQL"
        },
        {
            "time": "$9.99",
            "title": "Unity 3D"
        },
        {
            "time": "$7.99",
            "title": "Unity 2D"
        },
        {
            "time": "$3.99",
            "title": "AngularJS"
        },
        {
            "time": "$4.99",
            "title": "Django and Flask"
        },
        {
            "time": "$4.99",
            "title": "Visual Java"
        },
        {
            "time": "$7.99",
            "title": "Go"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You could use a javascript regex to replace the slashes with spaces when displaying it in the div and just use the hyphenated version for the div id.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There really isn't any use case justification for adding spaces to `id`s. It completely undermines the purpose of `id`s. For rendering purposes, it would be easy to remove any delimiter you use instead of a space.

Comment: Dan Weber's approach is the way to go

Comment: @DanWeber I haven't heard of regex do you have an example?

Comment: Sure, let me make a quick snippet.

Comment: It's impossible to figure out what you're talking about. Please edit the question and post relevant code here. Questions are expected to be self-contained so they don't expire. (BTW, in [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), space is the only disallowed character.)

Comment: Apologies ! mis read the OP ! Deleted my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you have a json object and want to create links by adding hyphens for the id and using the field as is for the link title.

You use a regex to replace the space with a hyphen when displaying it, and then leave it alone when using it as the link text.

To read about regexes (regular expressions):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

This segment of code replaces the space with a hyphen by using a regex. Adding the g after the clause tells it to replace all instances of it in the string. If you leave the g out it would only replace the first instance.

**sectionOfData[i].title.replace(/ /g, '-')**

**Updated to show OPs edited code:

```js
var data = {
    "L1": [
        {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "HTML"
        },
        {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "CSS"
        },
        {
            "time": "$2.99",
            "title": "Build a Site"
        },
        {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "Javascript"
        },
        {
            "time": "$3.99",
            "title": "Interactive Website"
        },
        {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "PHP"
        },
        {
            "time": "$4.99",
            "title": "Node.js"
        }
    ],
    "L2": [
       {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "Python"
        },
        {
            "time": "$2.99",
            "title": "Java"
        },
        {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "Ruby"
        },
        {
            "time": "$1.99",
            "title": "Ruby on Rails"
        },
        {
            "time": "$2.99",
            "title": "C++"
        },
        {
            "time": "$2.99",
            "title": "C#"
        },
        {
            "time": "$4.99",
            "title": "R"
        }
    ],
    "L3": [
       {
            "time": "Free",
            "title": "SQL"
        },
        {
            "time": "$9.99",
            "title": "Unity 3D"
        },
        {
            "time": "$7.99",
            "title": "Unity 2D"
        },
        {
            "time": "$3.99",
            "title": "AngularJS"
        },
        {
            "time": "$4.99",
            "title": "Django and Flask"
        },
        {
            "time": "$4.99",
            "title": "Visual Java"
        },
        {
            "time": "$7.99",
            "title": "Go"
        }
    ]
};

//console.log("Data: ", data["L1"]);

var loc = "L1";
var sectionOfData = data[loc];

var newContent = '';

for( var i = 0; i < sectionOfData.length; i++ ) {
  var currentItem = sectionOfData[i];

  // You can use console.log to debug or help while developing
  //console.log("Building row for item: ", currentItem);
  //console.log("Time: ", currentItem.time);
  
  newContent += '<li><span class="time">' + sectionOfData[i].time + '</span> ';
  newContent += '<a href="descriptions.html#"';

  // You are building a link here, so you need to add the id attribute next
  // You want to replace spaces with hyphens for the id.
  newContent += ' id="' + sectionOfData[i].title.replace(/ /g, '-') + '">';

  // Next would come your link text, followed by closing tags
  newContent += sectionOfData[i].title + '</a></li>';   
}

// Replace the contents of the session div with the newContent variable (which are the list items) using jquery
$('#sessions').html('<ul>' + newContent + '</ul>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sessions"></div>
```

Comment: Note that this is a process with information loss. If the input contained a hyphen already it will be incorrectly displayed as a space.

Comment: @IngoBürk One could prevent such loss by first replacing exisiting `-` with a special token, then running the replacement, then again restoring the tokenised `-`

Comment: @DanWeber I updated my OP, I can't find the area in the javascript that is affecting the display on the page.

Comment: These lines are displaying the id and link text respectively:   newContent += times[loc][i].title.replace(/ /g, '-') + '">';
      newContent += times[loc][i].title + '</a></li>';

Comment: So, you're a bit off. Let me update my code with your block.

Comment: Okay I see, there is code already in it to replace the json data with spaces to dashes. My professor didn't realize that, but all I need to do is name the data in json file with spaces and name the ID with dashes. Thanks for your help

Comment: Updated my code with a block that shows where you were going wrong. You did not have the id attribute before it. If you add some of the sample json returned from the call I can update the code to show it working.

Comment: Excellent, will update the code to use the JSON provided.

Comment: So you had it backwards, but no big deal. He is giving you json that contains a field called title. To use that field as an id for the element you replace the space with a hyphen using a regex. You then use the untouched value as the link text. I only iterated over a section of the json since that's what the code provided would do.